# how to generate pattern 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1

Tags: c

```
5 5 5 5 5
  4 4 4 4
    3 3 3
      2 2
        1
```

how  to generate pattern above pattern using c
 i tried this

```
int i, j, N;

scanf("%d", &N);

for(i=N; i>=1; i--)
{
    //Logic to print spaces
    for(j=N; j>i; j--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    //Logic to print numbers
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
    for(j=N; j>i; j--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: How to generate a good question? Read [ask] and include a [mcve].

Comment: `#include <stdio.h> int main() { printf("5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1n"); }` - I think this do

Comment: ahahah @EdHeal! But I think you forgot the `\n`s: #include <stdio.h> int main() { printf("5 5 5 5 5\n4 4 4 4\n3 3 3\n2 2\n1"); }

Comment: Give the full requirements for your task. Requirements by a single example only is inadequate. Also, describe the current behaviour of your code and ask a *specific* question about the code.

Comment: yes from next time onwards I will follow all the guide lines suggested by StackOverflow @Stargateur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginners should help beginners :-)

Here a slightly different approach:

```
for (int i=0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<5 ; j++)
    {
        if (j >= i)
            printf("%1d ", 5-i);
        else
            printf("  ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

We beginners should help each other.

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int n;

        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        printf( "\n" );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%*u", i + 1, ( n - i ) % 10 );
            for ( unsigned int j = i + 1; j < n; j++  ) printf( "%u", ( n - i ) % 10 );
            printf( "\n" );
        }

        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10

0000000000
 999999999
  88888888
   7777777
    666666
     55555
      4444
       333
        22
         1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

55555
 4444
  333
   22
    1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

If you need to include a blank between outputted digits then the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int n;

        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        printf( "\n" );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%*u", 2 * i + 1, ( n - i ) % 10 );
            for ( unsigned int j = i + 1; j < n; j++  ) printf( " %u", ( n - i ) % 10 );
            printf( "\n" );
        }

        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example its output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

5 5 5 5 5
  4 4 4 4
    3 3 3
      2 2
        1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

4 4 4 4
  3 3 3
    2 2
      1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

3 3 3
  2 2
    1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

2 2
  1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your program gives this output:

```
5 5 5 5 5
 4 4 4 4
  3 3 3
   2 2
    1
```

To get the output you want requires one very simple change. Because the characters are spaced, you need an extra space here:

```
//Logic to print spaces
for(j=N; j>i; j--)
{
    printf("  ");       // 2 spaces
}
```

New program output:

```
5 5 5 5 5
  4 4 4 4
    3 3 3
      2 2
        1
```

Answer (score 0):

You arr half way correct..just delete the 3 rd for loop inside the for loop..

```
scanf("%d", &N);

for(i=N; i>=1; i--)
{
    //Logic to print spaces
    for(j=N; j>i; j--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    //Logic to print numbers
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int i, j, N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (int i = N; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N - i; j++)
        {
            printf("  ");
        }

        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

output:

```
5 5 5 5 5 
  4 4 4 4 
    3 3 3 
      2 2 
        1
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping code here, you should explain *how* and *why* your code works.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

   
 int N;
    cin>>N;

    int i = 1;
    while(i <= N)
    {
        int j = 1;
        while (i>j)
        {
            cout<<" ";
            j=j+1;
        }
        
        int k = 1;
        while(k<=N-i+1)
        {
            cout<<N-i+1;
        
            k=k+1;
        }
        
        cout<<endl;
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so], but how does this code work and why is it different/better than the other answers?